# npm install fails with "Cannot find module 'glob'"

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, glob, node-modules

Here is the output on the console:

```
floydpink@MBP mean-app (master) $ npm install
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm  v2.0.0
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

npm ERR! Cannot find module 'glob'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/floydpink/Source/swara-server/mean-app/npm-debug.log
floydpink@MBP mean-app (master) $
```

And the npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install' ]
2 info using npm@2.0.0
3 info using node@v0.10.32
4 verbose node symlink /usr/local/bin/node
5 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'glob'
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
5 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
5 verbose stack     at require (module.js:380:17)
5 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/completion/file-completion.js:5:12)
5 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
5 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
5 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
5 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
6 verbose cwd /Users/floydpink/Source/swara-server/mean-app
7 error Darwin 13.4.0
8 error argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
9 error node v0.10.32
10 error npm  v2.0.0
11 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
12 error Cannot find module 'glob'
13 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
13 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
14 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I upgraded to this version of nodejs and npm a few days back and things have been fine until yesterday.

Could someone point me to the right direction in fixing this?

Comment: Did you try reverting back to the version of npm that comes with node v0.10.32 (npm v1.4.28)?

Comment: Thanks... As suggested by [@othiym23](https://github.com/othiym23) on [the issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6275) I raised at npm repo, I ran `brew update ; brew upgrade ; brew uninstall node ; brew install node` and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact issue. But I did not have brew on my Ubuntu Amazon EC2 instance(and I did not want to install it). I uninstalled npm using `sudo npm uninstall npm –g` and then ran the `make install` command again in the NPM directory to recompile npm and that fixed the issue.

Comment: The oiginal question was for Mac OS X and not Ubuntu Linux

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my Node.js was installed by the .pkg file(On a macOS). And tried reinstall npm but failed.

I solved this problem by uninstall the node totally follow this gist: https://gist.github.com/TonyMtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef